# What am I doing wrong with dygraph's showZeroValues option?

Tags: r, time-series, dygraphs, zero

I'm trying to plot several data series onto the same plot in R, but even with the `showZeroValues=TRUE` argument in `dyLegend()`, the legend stops showing values on mouseover when at least one of the series has a y=0 at the current x. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Below is a simplified example:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

x=data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2), b=c(2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 4, 5))
x$Date=seq(as.Date("2017-06-01"), (as.Date("2017-06-01")+dim(x)[1]-1), by="days")
d=xts(x, order.by=x$Date)[,1:2]

dygraph(d) %>%
  dyOptions(drawGrid=FALSE, fillGraph=TRUE) %>%
  dyLegend(labelsSeparateLines=TRUE, showZeroValues=TRUE)
```

On my computer the dynamic legend skips all x values at which one of the two series has y=0, as can be seen with the cursor being close to zeros but the legend still stuck on the right end of the graph: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a1Xb.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and found out that it was caused by the `xts` object containing character strings. The original data frame had a Date column, which I used to create the `xts` object, but I did not subset the numerical data. This resulted in the `xts` object being created but with character values (see [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855315/r-converting-dataframe-to-xts-adds-quotations-in-xts)). Surprisingly enough, the resulting plots were not much impacted, and the output was correct, which made troubleshooting less straightforward.

In your example, the following should solve the issue:

```
x=data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2), b=c(2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 4, 5))
x$Date=seq(as.Date("2017-06-01"), (as.Date("2017-06-01")+dim(x)[1]-1), by="days")
d=xts(x[, 1:2], order.by=x$Date) # This is the only change in your code

dygraph(d) %>%
  dyOptions(drawGrid=FALSE, fillGraph=TRUE) %>%
  dyLegend(labelsSeparateLines=TRUE, showZeroValues=TRUE)
```